# android development loading Images from URL

Tags: android, loading, image

I Know this question has been asked and answered but i have a different problem. I have a app out right now that wont load images that are higher than 5mp but loads smaller ones. Im not sure if its 5mp or over 1mb, Im pretty sure its mp though, I have tested. How can I load pictures that are all sizes? My code is below, Please help, please post code not links, of must to links then links to code that can help. Thanks!

**Downloading The Image**
  @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... objects) {
              InputStream is = null;
                      BufferedInputStream bis = null;

```
                   Bitmap bmp = null;

                   try {
                    URL url = new URL(Pictureurl);
                       URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                     conn.connect();
                     is = conn.getInputStream();
                      bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                      bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                      return bmp;
                 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                  return null;
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                  return null;
                   }
    }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object resizedBitmap) {
   MainPicture.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) resizedBitmap);
   connectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
         }
```

**Uploading the image**

public boolean SaveNewPicture(String SelectedFile, String UpdatedPhotoPath){

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = null;
 DataOutputStream dos = null;
 DataInputStream inStream = null;
 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

String Message = null;
     // The full path of filename which is to be uploaded to server
     String exsistingFileName = SelectedFile;

```
 String lineEnd = "\r\n";
 String twoHyphens = "--";
 String boundary = "*****";

 int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

 byte[] buffer;

 int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

String responseFromServer = "";

```
 //Server path to the upload.php
 String urlString = "http://www.thelinkhookup.com/upload.php";

 try
 {
 //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName) );

 // open a URL connection to the Servlet

 URL url = new URL(urlString);

 // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

 // Allow Inputs
 conn.setDoInput(true);

 // Allow Outputs
 conn.setDoOutput(true);

 // Don't use a cached copy.
 conn.setUseCaches(false);

 // Use a post method.
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

 dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );

 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

 System.out.println("Headers are written");

 // create a buffer of maximum size

 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

 // read file and write it into form...

 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

 while (bytesRead > 0)
 {
 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
 }

 // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

 // close streams
 System.out.println("File is written");
 fileInputStream.close();
 dos.flush();
 dos.close();

 }
 catch (MalformedURLException ex)
 {
 return false;
 }

 catch (IOException ioe)
 {
 Message = ioe.toString();
 return false;
 }

 //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE

 try {
 inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
 String str;

 while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
 {
 //the str contains the server response
 System.out.println("Server Response"+str);
 }
 inStream.close();
 //Message = "Should Have Worked";
 }

 catch (IOException ioex){

 return false;
 }
 try{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://thelinkhookup.com/UpdatePhotoName.php");
       List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
       postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", MyGlobalInfomation.getUsername()));
       postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Photopath", UpdatedPhotoPath));
       postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("localphotopath",SelectedFile ));
       UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
       request.setEntity(formEntity);
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
           if(SelectedFile != null || SelectedFile != ""){
           MyGlobalInfomation.setLocalPhotoPath(SelectedFile);
           }
      }
           catch(Exception e){
            return false;
}
     return true;
     }

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this against different websites or just one?

The only reason I ask is that you mentioned that > 1MB in size might be the cause. I know of some web hosting sites which provide free web space for their members but they're restricted to 1MB total per web page (or any other download). If the members want to have true download sites then they have to pay for the extra bandwidth involved.

Sorry, it probably doesn't answer your question but I thought you might want to check that it isn't the web site configuration before suspecting your code.

Comment: They said no. So it has something to do with the code. Someone mentioned something about BitmapFactory.Options.intsamplesize. You think that could help? If so please change my code a little to show me an example. Please help, This is the last thing i cant figure out.

Comment: I tried this as well, but no luck  BitmapFactory.Options size = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                         size.inSampleSize = 1;
                          bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis,null,size);